# JQuery causes conflicts when it's included

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I have a joomla template that uses Mootools , when i include jQuery ,Menu won't work and many other contents in the page too.

**My question:** Is there any solution to include jQuery without causing conflicts , i read a lot about `jQuery.noConflict()` but it's not working as expected.

Thanks

Comment: please tell us the Sourcecode?

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools

Comment: The problem is that i don't add any line of code,just including jQuery causes this problem

Comment: it was a mistake but this is not the problem

Comment: which version of MooTools and jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery 1.11.0 and  mootools 1.2.5

Answer (score 0):

you can find info about jQuery no conflict mode [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Basically you should use: `jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {` rather than `$( document ).ready(function( $ ) {`

Change every `$` that you are using for `jQuery`

Comment: You could also assign jQuery to a variable if you don't want to write that often the long 'jQuery'. var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: The problem is that i can't even include jQuery without causing errors